# Speed up image loading / appearance

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, image, loading

I am using Chromium Version 71.0.3578.80 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04 (64-bit). My browser loads the second image (from top) on my website within the first 500ms, but it shows it at about 1500ms:

[image]

I am using a bootstrap theme and my code to load the image looks as follows:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <section class="mb16 cover fullscreen image-bg"> 
        <div class="background-image-holder">
            <img alt="image" class="background-image" src="my_image.jpg">
            ...
        </div>
        ...
    </section>
    ...
</div>
```

Something is wring here. Is there a way to speed the appearance process up?

Answer (score 0):

There might not be a clear cut answer to this as there might be other blocking scripts/resources on your page that could affect the image from being rendered. You might want to have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Author_fast-loading_HTML_pages) for general tips on improving page rendering.